# Sqlite printing

Tags: android, database, sqlite

hi I have a SQLite Database and I've placed it in my assets folder. I was wondering how you can "print" information from the table on the screen. I have looked around and all I can find are people adding to a database all I want to do is show it on the screen and add some filters later on.

Answer (score 0):

It should be roughly like this:

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.your.app/your_path/yourdb.sqlite";

private static SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

public static void openDatabase() {

    String queryString="YOUR SQL QUERY HERE";

    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(queryString, null);

    if(cursor!=null) {

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while(!cursor.isLast()) {
             /*CHECK CURSOR USAGE AND DO SOMETHING WITH YOUR RESULTS HERE */
             cursor.moveToNext();
        } 
     }
     myDataBase.close();
}
```

Comment: sorry I'm new to this stuff is the query just the text your looking for and does it search all columns. so I have a column with a list of uni's and I want it to look up a particular uni and then print the info in the column next to it. How would i do that

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help.

1. Retrieve data from the SQLIte database and store them in a String / Strings.
2. Bring in some TextViews in your xml to your layout.
3. get references to those textview / textviews in your java code.
4. textview.settext(-----the string retrieved------);

This will print whatever string that your retrieved from your SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteDatabase database;

public int getId() {
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM <table_name>;

    int id = 0;

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        id = cursor.getInt(0);  // In my case, id (int) is in first column 
    }

    return id;
}
```